# How to Inflection a string to a model name in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

There is one `http://localhost:3000/me/posts/new?type=note`

I want to create a model by the params `type`in my controller and I have a model named Post::Note.

so how to create it by params[:type] string ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
note_klass = params[:type].camelize.constantize
note = note_klass.new
```

### RE: question edit

If your `Note` class is not global, you can use this:

```
const_name = params[:type].camelize
note_klass = Post.const_get(const_name)
```